# How do you sum consecutive years in sql

Tags: mysql

I am using the Lahman Baseball Database, http://seanlahman.com/files/database/readme2012.txt, and trying to query the database to list the total salary for two consecutive years, team name, and year for every team that had a total salary which was 1.5 times as much as for the previous year.

Having a hard time coming up with a query to sum up the salary's of all the players for each year and each team, and do that for 2 consecutive years. Not sure if that makes any since now, but I added what I am trying to achieve.

This is my query right now

```
Select S1.yearID, S1.teamID, S2.yearID, S2.teamID, sum(S1.salary),sum(S2.salary)
from salaries as S1 , salaries as S2
where S1.yearID +1 = S2.yearID and S1.teamID = S2.teamID
group by S1.teamID
```

This is the salaries table

```
CREATE TABLE "salaries" (
"yearID" int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
"teamID" varchar(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"lgID" varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"masterID" varchar(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"salary" float DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("yearID","teamID","lgID","masterID")
);
```

This is the query results I am trying to achieve[image]

Comment: now if we can only figure out how to get Charlie Hustle into Cooperstown. +1 for showing research effort (with the 8mb .sql file)

Answer (score 1):

Nearly there, just add them together in the column in the first line like this.

```
Select S1.yearID, S1.teamID, S2.yearID, S2.teamID, sum(S1.salary+S2.salary)
from salaries as S1 , salaries as S2
where S1.yearID +1 = S2.yearID and S1.teamID = S2.teamID
group by S1.teamID, S1.yearID
```

I think that should give what you are looking for, give it a try.

Edit : considering your comment and your update:

```
Select *, `Previous Salary`/`Salary` * 100 AS `Percent Increase` from (
Select S1.teamID AS `Team Name`, 
       S1.lgID AS `League`, 
       S1.yearID AS `Previous Year`, 
       sum(S1.salary) AS `Previous Salary`,
       S2.yearID AS `Year`,  
       sum(S2.salary) AS `Salary`
from salaries as S1 , salaries as S2
where S1.yearID -1 = S2.yearID and S1.teamID = S2.teamID
group by S1.teamID) salaries
```

Comment: Its only giving me 35 rows, I am trying to list every baseball team and there 2 year consecutive salary totals. This should result in 1000 + rows

Comment: I was missing the year group by, thats why, Ive added that

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am a moron though, I just need to sum the salary totals for each year from all the players. Like year 1985, sum up the total salary of the players for that team, and then sum the same thing for year 1986. I updated my question with the actual query I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated my query to correspond to your question update.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
create table salaries (yearid int, teamid int, salary int);
insert into salaries values 
(2010, 1, 1), (2012, 1, 2), (2013, 1, 3), (2014, 1, 4),
(2010, 2, 1), (2011, 2, 1), (2013, 2, 3), (2014, 2, 4);

select concat(coalesce(a.yearid,'na'), ' to ', coalesce(b.yearid,'na')) as yr, a.teamid, sum(coalesce(a.salary,0) + coalesce(b.salary,0)) as salary2yr
from salaries a
left join salaries b on 
    a.teamid = b.teamid and 
    a.yearid = b.yearid-1
group by a.teamid, concat(coalesce(a.yearid,'na'), ' to ', coalesce(b.yearid,'na'))
order by a.teamid, yr
```

Result

```
yr           | teamid | salary2yr
2010 to na   | 1      | 1
2012 to 2013 | 1      | 5
2013 to 2014 | 1      | 7
2014 to na   | 1      | 4
2010 to 2011 | 2      | 2
2011 to na   | 2      | 1
2013 to 2014 | 2      | 7
2014 to na   | 2      | 4
```